# Symfony2 Doctrine Expr 'IS NOT NULL'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the **FormType** for an **Entity** of mine, and setting up an [entity field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/entity.html).
I need two `Where` clauses in an `And`, and from what I've read on [the Query Builder page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html), this is at least how I should go about it:

```
'query_builder' => function ($er){
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->andx(
            $qb->expr()->in('p', '?1'),
            $qb->expr()->not(
                $qb->expr()->eq('p.location', 'NULL')
            )
        ))
        ->setParameter(1, $this->totalScope)
    ;
    return $qb;
},
```

However, the `not(eq('col', 'NULL'))` doesn't achieve the desired result, and in fact, errors with:

> Error: Expected Literal, got 'NULL'

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`isNotNull`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php#L459-L468):

```php
'query_builder' => function ($er){
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->andx(
            $qb->expr()->in('p', '?1'),
            $qb->expr()->isNotNull('p.location')
        ))
        ->setParameter(1, $this->totalScope);

    return $qb;
},
```

Answer (score 42):

You can also use DQL in your queryBuilder, which is much less *ugly* IMO.

Quick and dirty example from a controller:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Transaction');
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->where('t.timestamp > :timestamp')
    ->andWhere('t.pinNumber IS NOT NULL')
    ->setParameter('timestamp', new \DateTime('1 day ago'))
    ->getQuery()
;
```

Easier to read in my estimation.

Comment: For people that know SQL it might subjectively be **less ugly**, BUT its also **less portable**, whereas the expressions-way abstracts the database layer completely away. I personally always use the expressions.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard The isNotNull method: `public function isNotNull($x) { return $x . ' IS NOT NULL'; }`

Comment: Furthermore, the `IS NOT NULL` is DQL **not** SQL, making it **just as portable**, but also **less ugly**. :)

Comment: Interesting, so basically there is no advantage for SQL-Aware people of using expressions and I was wasting my time. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QueryBuilder to find the results,

```
 $query=$this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:DocumentName')
                 ->field('fieldName')->notEqual(null);

 $data=$query->getQuery()->execute();
```